# What happened to e-space?

Tags: doctor-who

In Doctor Who (the old series) why can't they get back into e-space? Does it still exist? Did it have any relevance to the alternate universe in the newer series?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They can't get back because they only got there by accident and the 4th Doctor isn't able to pilot the TARDIS very well, but it does still exist: he does go back eventually.  It's not related to the parallel universes / timeframes that the 9th through 11th Doctors experience.

The TARDIS originally entered E-Space through a [Charged Vacuum Emboitment (CVE)](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Charged_Vacuum_Emboitment) created by the Logopolitians.  After the events in Logopolis, only one CVE was left (and the Logopolitians were no longer around to make more), and this did eventually close (in [Timewyrm: Apocalypse](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0426203593)).  (In [The Invasion of E-Space](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1844354865) we do meet another race that can create CVEs).

Travel through the CVE wasn't a stable process, and the 5th Doctor says (in [Earthshock](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0562842/)) that it would be extremely difficult for the TARDIS to travel to "negative coordinate space", and that this wouldn't occur accidentally.  This effectively means that E-Space was cut off from N-Space at least for the Doctor at this point in this timeline.

However, the 7th Doctor, better at piloting the TARDIS, was able to travel between E-space and N-space, and brought Romana back (in [Blood Harvest](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0426204174)).

E-Space wasn't a parallel universe like we've seen in the 9th through 11th Doctor episodes; it was more of a [pocket universe](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Pocket_universe).  See also the [TARDIS Index File on E-Space](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/E-Space).